# Creating tables for multiple DbContext's using the same database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement multiple DbContext's targeting the same database.

It works when calling DataBase.EnsureCreated() on the first DbContext object, but it doesnt create tables for the remaining objects.
After Init.Initalize() I want the database to contain two tables named Clients and Addresses

**Initalize database:**

```
public static class Init
{
    public static void Initalize(BaseDbContext[] contexts, Config.Options.Environments environment)
    {                     
        if (environment == Config.Options.Environments.Development)
        {
            contexts[0].Database.EnsureDeleted();

            foreach(BaseDbContext context in contexts)
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            var clients = new Client[]
            {
                new Client() { Key = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Smokers.no", DisplayName = "Smokers.no", Email = "post@smokers.no", LogoFilename = "logo.jpg" }
            };

            foreach(BaseDbContext context in contexts)
            {
                if (context.GetType().Equals(typeof(Data.SharedDbContext)))
                {
                    var cntx = context as Data.SharedDbContext;
                    foreach (Client client in clients) { cntx.Clients.Add(client); }
                    cntx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            foreach(BaseDbContext context in contexts)
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                if (context.GetType().Equals(typeof(Data.SharedDbContext)))
                {
                    var cntx = context as Data.SharedDbContext;

                    if (cntx.Clients.Any())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseDbContext:**

```
public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

**SharedDbContext:**

```
public class SharedDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    public SharedDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    #region DbSets
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

**MailerDbContext:**

```
public class MailerDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    SharedDbContext _context;

    public MailerDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options, SharedDbContext context) : base(options)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public SharedDbContext LCToolsContext
    {
        get
        {
            return _context;
        }
    }

    #region DbSets
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2874

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a Configuration where you set the `ContextKey` for each separate context?

E.g:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDataContext>
{
 public Configuration()
 {
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
   ContextKey = "MySpecialKey";
 }

 //Seed method here..

}
```

Call it like this:

```
private static void InitializeDatabaseUsingEF()
{

  System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
    new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<
      MyDataContext,
      Migrations.Configuration>("ConnectionString.PostgreSql (Npgsql)"));

  using (var db = new MyDataContext())
  {
    db.Database.Initialize(true);        
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the design and now everything works as expected.

**Initalize database:**

```
public static class Init
{
    public static void Initalize(DbContext[] contexts, Config.Options.Environments environment)
    {                     
        if (environment == Config.Options.Environments.Development)
        {
            foreach(DbContext cntx in contexts)
            {
                if (cntx.GetType().Equals(typeof(GenericDbContext)))
                {
                    cntx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    cntx.Database.EnsureCreated();
                }
            }

            var clients = new Client[]
            {
                new Client() { Key = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Smokers.no", DisplayName = "Smokers.no", Email = "post@smokers.no", LogoFilename = "logo.jpg" }
            };

            foreach(DbContext cntx in contexts)
            {
                if (cntx.GetType().Equals(typeof(GenericDbContext)))
                {
                    var context = cntx as GenericDbContext;
                    foreach (Client client in clients) { context.Clients.Add(client); }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(DbContext cntx in contexts)
            {
                cntx.Database.EnsureCreated();

                if (cntx.GetType().Equals(typeof(GenericDbContext)))
                {
                    var context = cntx as GenericDbContext;
                    if (context.Clients.Any())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GenericDbContext:**

```
public class GenericDbContext : DbContext
{
    public GenericDbContext(DbContextOptions<GenericDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Models.Mailer.Address>().ToTable("MailerAddresses");
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Mailer.Address> MailerAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

**MailerDbContext:**

```
public class MailerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MailerDbContext(DbContextOptions<MailerDbContext> options, GenericDbContext generic) : base(options)
    {
        this.GenericDbContext = generic;
    }

    public GenericDbContext GenericDbContext { get; set; }
}
```